# Python search a specific text file in multiple subdirectories for a specific string & then replace another string within same file with found string

Tags: python, string, search

Python search a specific text file in multiple subdirectories for a specific string & then replace another string within same file with found string.

To explain this case:
I have a bunch of *.xml files in multiple directories and each of these files contains two strings at different locations.

```xml
<spirit:name>I_want_to_take_this_string</spirit:name>

<spirit:modelName>And_paste_it_here</spirit:modelName>
```

What I am trying to do is to take the string value **I_want_to_take_this_string** and replace **And_paste_it_here** within the same file, then move on to the next file and then move on to the next until it can't find any more files to make the swap.

The output should look like this

```xml
<spirit:name>I_want_to_take_this_string</spirit:name>

<spirit:modelName>I_want_to_take_this_string</spirit:modelName>
```

I believe it's probably the easiest thing to do here but this is the first python code I want to write as a beginner.

Thanks in advance for helping with this.

Comment: Its not clear. you say each file contain two strings: `<spirit:name>I_want_to_take_this_string</spirit:name>` and `<spirit:modelName>And_paste_it_here</spirit:modelName>` (so the file already contains this) Then you say you want to replace `I_want_to_take_this_string` for `And_paste_it_here`? So at the end you will have something like: `<spirit:name>And_paste_it_here</spirit:name>`
`<spirit:modelName>And_paste_it_here</spirit:modelName>`?  then you mention a swap, something like `<spirit:name>And_paste_it_here</spirit:name>`
`<spirit:modelName>I_want_to_take_this_string</spirit:modelName>`

Comment: can you just post a sample of the input file and a sample of the output file so we know what do you need?

Comment: Break the task into a series of steps, then work out how to do each part. e.g. start with just one file. How to open and modify an xml file with Python? Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Example: 
=======


What is currently present in the files under different directories:
=========================================
<spirit:name>css600_tmcram_etf_dw32_fsd2_16kB</spirit:name>

<spirit:modelName>css600_tmcram</spirit:modelName>

======================================
What I want to change it to after the python script executes:
======================================
<spirit:name>css600_tmcram_etf_dw32_fsd2_16kB</spirit:name>

<spirit:modelName>css600_tmcram_etf_dw32_fsd2_16kB</spirit:modelName>




Does this explain what I want to achieve?

TIA Appreciated